# How to exclude @ConfigurationProperties from reloading in kubernetes configMap

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

In my application I have ds bean with prefix so I can defined it in `application.properties` by profile

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "atomikos.db")
public AbstractDataSourceBean dbDataSource() {
    AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean atomikosDataSource = new AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean();    
    return atomikosDataSource;
}
```

according [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#propertysource-reload) article this bean will be reload when configMap changed but how I can exclude it and still use `application.properties` to define properties this bean according to profile ? In production system I just can not recreate connection to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/#refresh-scope), you should set

```
spring.cloud.refresh.never-refreshable=my.package.ClassName
```

where `my.package.ClassName` is the type of bean you don't want refreshed.